# Css Scroll is not working for the first time

Tags: jquery, ajax, css, scroll

CSS Scroll isn't working for the first time.

The page is called from an AJAX call and `Current Table` is generated with jQuery. The table doesn't show scroll for the first time (scroll is not working), but when we reload the page it works. There is no div over lapping

```css
table.effort-Table,
table.inner-eff-table{
    background-color: #eeedee;
    border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    top: 25px;
    font-family: 'arial';}


table.inner-eff-table{
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: 0; 
}

table.effort-Table tr td,
table.inner-eff-table tr td {
  font-size: 16px;
  display:table-cell;
  font-family: 'arial';
  color: #2d292a;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align:middle ;
  border-bottom:1px solid #c5c5c5;
  border-right:1px solid #c5c5c5;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  height: 28px;
}

table.effort-Table tr:last-child td,
table.inner-eff-table tr:last-child td,
table.inner-eff-table tr:nth-child(12) td{
            border-bottom:0;
}

table.effort-Table tr td:nth-child(2){
    padding: 0px;
}
table.effort-Table tr:nth-child(1) td,
table.inner-eff-table tr:nth-child(1) td{
 background: #4a4a4a; 
 color: #fff;
}
.effort-Table-head{
 color:#ffffff !important;
 background: #4a4a4a !important;
 text-align:center !important;
 padding-left: 0 !important;
 border-right:1px solid #c5c5c5 !important;
}

#tab1 table tbody  tr:nth-child(1)  th{background: #4a4a4a !important;}

 
.inner-eff-table{
 padding: 0;
 border-right:none;
    background-color: #eeedee;
 }
table.inner-eff-table tr td:last-child {
 border-right:none;
 }
table.inner-eff-table tr:last-child > td{
 border-bottom:none;
 }
table.effort-Table .inner-eff-table{
    width: 100%;
   
}
table.inner-eff-table tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(1),
table.inner-eff-table tr:nth-child(6) td:nth-child(1),
table.inner-eff-table tr:nth-child(11) td:nth-child(1),
table.inner-eff-table tr:nth-child(12) td{
 height: 36px;}

.inner-eff-table td,
.inner-eff-table td:nth-child(2){
    min-width: 120px;
     padding: 4px 10px;
   
}
.inner-eff-table td{
 background-color: #eeedee !important;
 color:#000 !important;
 font-family: 'arial';
    
}
.inner-eff-table tr:nth-child(1) td{
     background: #4a4a4a !important;
    color: #fff !important;;
    
}
 .search-table-outter {  
  width: 734px;
}
.test-scroll{
 overflow-x: scroll; 
 border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
 border-left: none;
}
.test-scroll::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    
}


.scroll{
    width: 700px;
}
```

```html
                 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="inner-eff-table"><tbody><tr><td colspan="5">some text</td><td colspan="4">some text</td><td colspan="4">some text</td><td colspan="4">some text</td></tr><tr><td>some text</td><td>some text</td><td>some text</td><td>some text</td><td>some text</td><td>some text</td><td>text</td><td>some text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>some text</td><td>some text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td></tr><tr><td>200</td><td>200</td><td>200</td><td>200</td><td>200</td><td>200</td><td>200</td><td>200</td><td>200</td><td>200</td><td>200</td><td>200</td><td>200</td><td>200</td><td>200</td><td>200</td><td>200</td></tr><tr><td>20</td><td>20</td><td>20</td><td>20</td><td>20</td><td>20</td><td>20</td><td>20</td><td>20</td><td>20</td><td>20</td><td>20</td><td>20</td><td>20</td><td>20</td><td>20</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>3.5</td><td>3.5</td><td>3</td><td>2.5</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>3.5</td><td>3</td><td>3.5</td><td>3</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td></tr><tr><td>250.00</td><td>285.71</td><td>285.71</td><td>333.33</td><td>400.00</td><td>1000.00</td><td>1000.00</td><td>1000.00</td><td>1000.00</td><td>285.71</td><td>333.33</td><td>285.71</td><td>333.33</td><td>909.09</td><td>909.09</td><td>909.09</td><td>909.09</td></tr><tr><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td></tr><tr><td>16000.00</td><td>14000.00</td><td>14000.00</td><td>12000.00</td><td>10000.00</td><td>4000.00</td><td>4000.00</td><td>4000.00</td><td>4000.00</td><td>14000.00</td><td>12000.00</td><td>14000.00</td><td>12000.00</td><td>4400.00</td><td>4400.00</td><td>4400.00</td><td>4400.00</td></tr><tr><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td><td>1.1</td></tr><tr><td>19360.00</td><td>16940.00</td><td>16940.00</td><td>14520.00</td><td>12100.00</td><td>4840.00</td><td>4840.00</td><td>4840.00</td><td>4840.00</td><td>16940.00</td><td>14520.00</td><td>16940.00</td><td>14520.00</td><td>5324.00</td><td>5324.00</td><td>5324.00</td><td>5324.00</td></tr><tr><td>1840</td><td>1840</td><td>1840</td><td>1840</td><td>1840</td><td>1840</td><td>1840</td><td>1840</td><td>1840</td><td>1840</td><td>1840</td><td>1840</td><td>1840</td><td>1840</td><td>1840</td><td>1840</td><td>1840</td></tr><tr><td width="109">183436.00</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ashish9342/5yr3yo1n/)

Comment: You mean there's no Y-scroll? I don't think there's supposed to be any, it fits fully on the Y-axis, while the X-axis scroll is there in the fiddle. So please elaborate a little if possible.

Comment: @sphanley: yes there should be no yscroll. I am getting the correct output. 

The current output is not reflecting in native app (iOS) for the 1st time (i.e, there is no scroll coming in output, only content inside the div width 700 is seen and other data is truncated) but when i close the app and login again the scroll comes.

Comment: @sphanley I have updated the fiddle code.

Code tells how i am generating the table, based upon some input selection.
I want scroll to come in first time, when user logs in and select the input

Comment: I think you're trying to reply to @user326964 rather than myself, I just edited the question to fix the casing in your title.